# Navigating to another URL during webdriver task

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to log into a website as an admin and then navigate to another page (a portal) which requires this admin login beforehand to display data. I don't think I can access the cookies because of an issue accessing https cookies issue I read up on earlier (correct me if I'm wrong).

So my current solution is to enter the url as soon as the login process is complete and then continue with other tasks. Could you please advise on the methods/functions I can use to do this? If there are better ways to do this, I'd also be happy to hear about those!

```
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
var By = require("selenium-webdriver").By;
var until = require("selenium-webdriver").until;
var assert = require("chai").assert;
var filename = "img";
var fs = require('fs');
var err = "error caught!";
var testName = "get_login_cookies";

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

describe('email register', function ()  {
    this.timeout(25000);

before(function(done) {
    driver.navigate().to('https://www.perlego.com/#');
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies;
    driver.manage().window().maximize()
    .then(() => done())
});

it('logs in with admin user and gets cookies', (done) => {

    driver.findElement(By.name('email')).sendKeys("user@example.com");
    driver.findElement(By.css('#password')).sendKeys("examplePassword");
    driver.findElement(By.css('.login-button')).click();

    // some code here to navigate to other page via url

    // runs remainder of tests

});

after(function(done) {
    driver.quit()
    .then(() => done())
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found that it was as simple as running the driver.navigate() method where I wanted to go to a new page:

driver.navigate().to('https://www.somesite.com/#');

Because of the cookie settings on the site, I was unable to access them with the webdriver, so I had to enter the password each time.

I was tripped up by waiting for ajax calls on the page when trying to select elements, this method helped:

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000);

Hope this helps someone out there!